# unable to make android stick do 1920x1080

Tags: screen-resolution

I bought two 3188 quad core android sticks to play with. Each is hooked up to a big screen TV. Each TV also has a PC on a different HDMI port. I want to use the android sticks to replace the PCs. If windows is needed I plan to remote into the machine downstairs. The problem is getting an RDP client to work. There are many RDP clients. Each has something different wrong. I tried all of them. The best functioning for this use is the Microsoft RDP client. It comes closest to being on the actual computer and does as well as wibdows to windows RDP. But it will not do 1920x1080. It did have that but they removed it, and now it does not have custom resolution.

The problem is the android stick does not go beyond 1280x720. When experimenting I did get one RDP client to do extremely high resolution with little tiny print on the screen, beyond 1920x1080, but the software had other issues. That proves the android stick has the capability.

I installed software to change the resolution. If I reduce below 1280x720 the display shrinks to the upper left corner leaving black bars. If I go above 1280x720 the display expands off the right edge and bottom. 1280x720 represents a barrier for some reason. Changing the DPI causes text to be larger or smaller, not providing the desired effect. As I said, when playing with it, I was able to get higher resolution, but it was just that one program, and it does not apply to the launcher and other applications.

These android sticks are really cool. The audio and video functionality is amazing. When I watch TV shows there is excellent detail, again proving the capability of the device to do the resolution I want. There is little to no desktop focus for the device. It's a phone system expecting touch. I think this will improve over time and people will use them more as desktops or thin clients. It's tiny, powerful, low energy, low maintenance, low heat.

The android sticks are quad core 3188 with two gigs memory, 8 gigs storage, running android 4.4.2. If someone knows how to configure android to go past 1280x720 on the device please advise. Thanks